# Load data from cache after ajax load

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, caching

I have loaded a popup menu with subcategory list in ajax by click event.

For eg: there is 10 main category each category has many list of subcategory and it loaded in the popup by ajax. When i click on category A it loads category A's subcategory and when i moved to category B it loads the catagory B's subcategory and when i comes back & click on category A again the request going to server again and takes same time to load.

I need to load this data from cache. When i set `cache: true` in ajax function again it still loads and sending request.

I don't need a request again to the server for the same data ie. category A. is there a way to do this?

And also is it possible to re-request the server again if failed due to no internet connectivity?

Code:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/category/list/',
   data:'catid='+$(".category").attr('data-id'),
   cache: true,
   dataType:'json',
   beforeSend:function()
   {
    $(".subcatlist").html('<div class="loader">loading...</div>');
   }
   success:function(json){
     $(".loader").remove();
     $(".subcatlist").html(json.sublist);
   }
   error:function()
   {
     console.log('error');
   }

});
```

Comment: What does the receiving php script look like? Which headers are sent by the php script?

Comment: I have loaded the html in the json array. and i didn't defined any headers in the code. May be by default it loads a json type content.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that at the very top of your php script receiving the Ajax call:

```
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime("+2 day"));
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime("+2 day")));
```

This should tell the browser the result of the Ajax call can be cached for two days.

Answer (score 0):

I use that in top of my scripts file, for example: **function.js / default.js / admin.js**, or after `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Enable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: true
});
```

Comment: I've already defined cache:true in my function. can u pls tell me What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Which I know, if ajaxSetup not use the cache still working (or not) in Internet Explorer. In other browsers, the cache option by itself works.